# cloud_firestore/permission-denied Missing or insufficient permissions?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I got this error any one tell me how to solve it. my firebase rules is correct according to documentation and my login function below code how to solve this error?

My firebase rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if true;

    }
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
  loginAdmin() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("admins").get().then((snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
        if (result.data()["id"] != _adminIdTextEditingController.text.trim()) {
          // ignore: deprecated_member_use
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text("Your id is not Correct.."),
          ));
        } else if (result.data()["password"] !=
            _passwordTextEditingController.text.trim()) {
          // ignore: deprecated_member_use
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text("Your password is not Correct.."),
          ));
        } else {
          // ignore: deprecated_member_use
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text("Welcome Dear Admin." + result.data()["name"]),
          ));

          setState(() {
            _adminIdTextEditingController.text = "";
            _passwordTextEditingController.text = "";
          });
          Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => HomeScreen());
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that rule is deployed to the live db?

Answer (score -1):

some of the firebase rules is giver below you can use with your own

1. No Security

```
{
  "rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": true
  }
 }
```

2.Full security

```
{
 "rules": {
  ".read": false,
  ".write": false
   }
 }
```

3.Only authenticated users can access/write data

```
{
 "rules": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null"
  }
 }
```

4.Validates timestamp is not a future value

```
{
  "rules": {
   "posts": {
   "$uid": {
     "timestamp": { 
       ".validate": "newData.val() <= now" 
       }
      }
     }
    }
  }
```

5.Prevents Delete or Update

```
{
  "rules": {
  "posts": {
   "$uid": {
     ".write": "!data.exists()"
         }
       }
     }
   }
```